# Ubuntu mail command - where does it store sent mail?

Tags: ubuntu, email

I am very new to Ubuntu and have an issue where sent mail from our Ubuntu Server has been failing for a number of weeks. We are using the mail command (invoked from PHP) like so:

```
mail("mygroup@ourGmailDomain", "Subject", "Message", "Header");
```

I can see from the file /var/log/mail.log the e-mail being attempted to send and it is failing to deliver. Does the "mail" tool store a copy of what it has sent somewhere?

There has probably been no configuration of the mail settings. This is not a tool I am at all familiar with, so any pointers into how to find sent mail, or even turn it on so all attempts at sending are now stored, is very much appreciated.

**Update with my findings:**

I believe that the sent e-mails were never stored, so I've lost 2 weeks worth of e-mails from my users. So I need to modify my setup to automatically store e-mails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local mail directory by default is /var/mail/
If the mail is designated to the local user like root@localhost, it will go to /var/mail/root

Comment: I dreaded this... so if /var/mail has a single file called "root" which has a size 0, then there is no mail being stored?

Comment: if mail is sent to root, it will be stored at /var/spool/mail/root. If it is sent to an external address and it fails, you might run the command 'mailq' at the terminal to see if mail is still being queued for delivery.

Comment: @LHWizard /var/spool/mail/root is a file of 0 size. "mailq" states "Mail queue is empty".

Comment: if mailq is empty, then the mail has left the server successfully and been deleted. I would then think that your google group is not receiving the mail correctly. don't forget to check the mail.log for more clues.

Comment: I think I'm hosed here... I don't think I'm going to be able to see the e-mail that wasn't delivered. Thanks anyway. Do you know how I can set up "mail" to store any e-mails that are sent

Comment: adding a second recipient comes to mind, it could be a local user like root or ubuntu as long as you're mindful of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned Ubuntu, I will assume that your server has postfix installed. Make sure to look at the /var/log/mail.log file for errors due to the mail failing.

Comment: Yeah, the file mail.log shows many errors being sent (see my other question: http://serverfault.com/questions/676751/no-longer-able-to-send-e-mails-from-ubuntu-server-to-gmail-group ) . I am just desperate to try find copies of the e-mails so I can see who tried to get in touch with us.